# Expo developer menu not showing

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was working with expo tool and react native without any problem but after upgrading Expo Go app on my  emulator , It got a problem . The developer menu won't show like before . And the items in the menu won't display . My expo go version : 2.25.1
I am using Genymotion emulator.

[image: Like this :]

any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

check the dependencies in your package.json, if you have "react-native-reanimated": "someversion", delete it, and everything works. If reanimated is an essenential dependencies, remote debug from your phone will work.

After deleting reanimated, run npm install or yarn install.

Comment: I checked package.json  . there is no package named 'react-native-reanimated'.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with android emulator from google?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had a very similar problem on iOS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521167/developer-menu-appears-transparent-on-ios). In my case, I had to add & trust my corporate proxy's certificate on the simulator so that Expo Go could download some assets. It might be worth a look in your case, too.